# Managing exit of a user from a game 'room' on React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

This might seem complicated - I am working on a game app on React that involves users all joining a certain `<Route>` in my project. When all users are on this route, the game is unpaused and if not the game is paused.

My question is: How can I manage to suddenly pause the game if a user leaves the link or closes the tab ? Is there any way to actively check this on react? I figured useEffect hook might be useful but I don't know how to get the number of users leaving a site or closing the tab in real-time at once.

Here is some basic code to understand what I want. I have a functional React component `<GameSession>` that hosts a game when users join this link:

```
const GameSession = ({userRegistered}) =>{

  const [paused, setPaused] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
  // store some user related data in localStorage when the user loads

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
  setPaused(numberofUsersInGame === totalUsers ? false : true)
  }, [numberofUsersInGame]);
 /* MY PROBLEM IS IN THIS EFFECT HOOK ABOVE. HOW TO CHECK IF A USER HAS LEFT THIS 
COMPONENT OR PAGE SO I CAN UPDATE numberofUsersInGame ? */

   if(!userRegistered)
   return <Redirect to="/dashboardpage">

   if(paused)               
  return <PausedComponent /> /*this component should fire a return when total
                               number of users registered to this game is not
                               equal to current number of users who are
                               active on the GameSession component (this link)*/

   return (
      <Fragment>
      <GameComponent>
      </Fragment>
      );


};
GameSession.propTypes = {
// PropTypes go here
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
//states go here
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GameSession);
```

Comment: Have you considered using sockets?

Comment: Please give me some more info. So, I can help you.
Are you using any server for this?

Please add your code to sandbox and give a URL of that.

Comment: @ChetanKumar I have added some code for more info

Comment: @MorKadosh not yet. Do you mean websockets ?

Comment: @RahulPillai I do. they can give you easy indication of connected/disconnected clients

Comment: Thanks @MorKadosh. WIll have a look and let you know.

Comment: @MorKadosh I had an opportunity to look into websocket.io and it looks like it might actually work. Thanks for the suggestion. I am new to web dev and really enjoying building my site. I tried googling my problem but sometimes google just doesn't know what a human exactly wants :)

Comment: @RahulPillai Do you want to use only front end for this game?

Comment: It's quite detailed and involves a lot of data. I am making use of redux store to make my data accessible. I suppose the best alternative is to use it front end but make periodic saves to the back end incase a user disconnects.